# How to align many textboxes to different td table?

Tags: html, css

[image: tz]

I would like to align these textboxes to each td (except the blank one) and also giving them the same size than these td. It might be very easy to do but I'm a beginner with html.

Here is my html code now :

```
<div class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
        <input class="form-control" id="moMeca" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
        <input class="form-control" id="moCarro" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
        <input class="form-control" id="moPeint" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
        <input class="form-control" id="moDepa" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
        <input class="form-control" id="moCessions" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
        <input class="form-control" id="piecesMeca" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
    </div>
```

Comment: please add a working snippet with your css

Comment: My css is simply bootstrap

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It would be quite difficult to align them without enclosing them in the table itself.

Comment: @zelitomas don't recommend a third party site. Use Snippet.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put them in the `<thead>` ?

Comment: You should add them to table's cells. It is the easiest way to make them width of cells and perfect align.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you could do 
 1. You could use table structure if you do not have form element in html.
 2. Use Bootstrap class row for major div then make different div's inside parent div of fix sizes then you could handle your form element also.

I am attaching table structure here.

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/95m2nhth/1/

```js
$('table tbody tr:first-child td').each(function(i){
 var w = $(this).width();
 $('.input:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')').css('width',w);
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid;
}

input {
  padding: 0.3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-inline">
    <input class="input" id="annualBudget" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
    <input class="input" id="moMeca" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
    <input class="input" id="moCarro" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
    <input class="input" id="moPeint" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
    <input class="input" id="moDepa" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
    <input class="input" id="moCessions" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
    <input class="input" id="piecesMeca" type="text" style="width:auto;" value="">
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>Testing ABC</td>
      <td>Te</td>
      <td>Increase in td size</td>
      <td>Incearse</td>
      <td>Testing with long long text</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You have to get the width of each `td` and then assign it to `input text box`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add another row to your table:

```css
table  { border: 2px solid black; }
th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr><th>Budget annuel
      <th>M.O. Mécanique
      <th>M.O. Carroserie
      <th>M.O. Peinture
      <th>M.O. Dépannage
      <th>M.O. Cessions
      <th>Pièces Méca
 <tbody>
  <tr><td><input class="form-control" id="annualBudget" type="text" value="">
      <td><input class="form-control" id="moMeca" type="text" value="">
      <td><input class="form-control" id="moCarro" type="text" value="">
      <td><input class="form-control" id="moPeint" type="text" value="">
      <td><input class="form-control" id="moDepa" type="text" value="">
      <td><input class="form-control" id="moCessions" type="text" value="">
      <td><input class="form-control" id="piecesMeca" type="text" value="">
</table>
```